# How to fix error "AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'writerow'" while entering date in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

Im writing a program that will check if the date that the user enters is valid and then writes them in a csv file. But when i write them in the file I'm getting an error like this.

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'writerow'
```

This is a part of my code:

```
import csv
from datetime import date

while True:
    amt=int(input("\nENTER THE AMOUNT "))
    if amt>monthlyincome:
        print("YOU HAVE SPENT MORE THAN YOUR MONTHLY INCOME!PLEASE TRY AGAIN")
    else:
        break

while True:
    dat=input("ENTER DATE (DD/MM/YYYY):")
    d=date.today()
    format="%d/%m/%y"
    time1=d.strftime(format)
    if dat>time1:
        print("PLEASE ENTER A VALID DATE")
    else:
        break

data=[amt,dat]
exp.append(data)
for i in exp:
    d.writerow(str(i))
```

What should I change here?

Comment: `d` is a `datatime` instance, not a CSV file. There's isn't enough code in your question to tell you how to fix it…

Comment: @martineau well this was a stupid mistake.. thanks to you i found out that i had used d as a datetime variable as well as a writerow object. Good that you mentioned that 'd'.

Comment: Neethu: Good to hear you got the problem solved. Mistakes like that happen to all of us at some point — welcome to the club! `;¬>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually `d` is a date time object, and `writerow` is method of csv module. To write rows try like:

```
f = open('numbers2.csv', 'w')
with f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(d)
```